# Забрать значение из блока.React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть следующие блоки:

```
<MDBCol md="4">
    <div className="branch" onClick={func}>
        <h5>Врач хирург</h5>
    </div>
</MDBCol>
<MDBCol md="4">
    <div className="branch" onClick={func}>
        <h5>Врач терапевт</h5>
    </div>
</MDBCol>
<MDBCol md="4">
    <div className="branch" onClick={func}>
        <h5>Врач кардиолог</h5>
    </div>
</MDBCol>
```

Я могу как-то из них забирать значение по клику, чтобы оно хранилось в памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создадим функцию и назовем ее `addValueToArray`, она будет навешиваться на все дивы, которые содержат описание, которое нужно достать при клике и сохранить. Значения будем хранить в массиве `values` в стейте компонента. При сохранении знового значения в стейт использовал spread syntax, чтобы не вызвать мутацию стейта, что может привести к сайд эффекту.

Через [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) - получить элемент, в котором в данный момент обрабатывается событие, а через [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) - получить текстовое содержимое элемента и его потомков. Проверка черех [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) добавлена, чтобы уже существующие значения в массиве не попали в него снова.

Рабочий пример кода:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      values: []
    };

    this.addValueToArray = this.addValueToArray.bind(this);
  }

  addValueToArray(e) {
    const { textContent } = e.currentTarget;
    const { values } = this.state;
    if (values.indexOf(textContent) === -1) {
      this.setState({
        values: [...this.state.values, textContent]
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Врачи</h1>
        <div onClick={this.addValueToArray}>
          <h5>хирург</h5>
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.addValueToArray}>
          <h5>терапевт</h5>
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.addValueToArray}>
          <h5>кардиолог</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Кто был выбран?</h4>
          <ul>
            {this.state.values.map((value, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{value}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полезные ссылки:

- [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)